# Adding the values in specific columns according to the group type

Tags: r

So I have some numerical values for samples a,b,c, and I have a different measuring events (rows) which belong to different groups (x,y or z - first column)
For example, this is my data frame:

[image]

And I want to make a data frame in which I will get added Values for samples A,B and C according to the "Group" column like this:

[image]

Tnx!

Lada

Comment: For a tidyverse solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62374420/5221626

Comment: With `library(dplyr)`, `your_data |> summarize(across(everything(), sum), .by = Group)`

Comment: Thank you Phil and Gregor, these are easy and nice solutions and they are working!